# How to convert results into a table-Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert my results into a table.

Here is my code:

```
from cbapi.response import *
import logging 

cb = CbResponseAPI() 

query = cb.select(Watchlist) # returns a Query object

for proc in query: # uses the iterator to retrieve all results
    dd=[proc.name,proc.last_hit_count]
    print(dd)
```

Here is my output:

```
['name1', 4]
['name2', 6]
['name3', 3]
```

I am trying to get the output to be outputted as a table, like this:

```
Name   Last_Hit_count

name1      4
name2      6
name3      3
```

I am new to python so any ideas and suggestions would help.

Comment: Write it to a CSV file with a CSV writer.

Comment: you can do inside the for loop: `print(proc.name, proc.last_hit_count, sep='\t')`

Comment: You missed the headers